# UTC_timestamp in mysql return wrong value

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

Don't know why the UTC time gets converted again to UTC.

Retrieve : `2017-08-29T23:49:46:000Z`

DB : `2017-08-30 05:19:46`

MySql:

[image]

```
db.query('INSERT INTO history SET created=utc_timestamp(), ?', values,
```

Table value:

[image]

Retrieve:

[image]

In Json client Side :

```
 {
     "created": "2017-08-29T23:49:46.000Z",
 }
```

How to achieve correct value at client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `timezone: 'utc'` to your database configuration (which you would have declared it as a var) in node.js

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't get, can you please describe more, I am new to MYSql.

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `index.js` code (where you establish your mysql connectivity from node.js) ?

Comment: Never mind I got the configuration and tested, it works for me : var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: settings.dbhost,
    user: settings.user,
    password: settings.password,
    database:settings.database,    
    timezone: 'utc'
});